# system-config-samba crash with could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf'

Tags: samba, cifs, troubleshooting

OS: Linux Mint 18.3 Xfce 64-bit.

I am trying to re-install `samba`, so far I've done:

```
sudo apt-get install samba cifs-utils system-config-samba
```

But when running the configuration GUI:

```
sudo system-config-samba
```

it crashes like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/system-config-samba", line 45, in <module>
    mainWindow.MainWindow(debug_flag)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/mainWindow.py", line 121, in __init__
    self.basic_preferences_win = basicPreferencesWin.BasicPreferencesWin(self, self.xml, self.samba_data, self.samba_backend, self.main_window)
  File "/usr/share/system-config-samba/basicPreferencesWin.py", line 97, in __init__
    self.admin = libuser.admin()
SystemError: could not open configuration file `/etc/libuser.conf': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suffice to create that file:

```
sudo touch /etc/libuser.conf
```

And re-run the samba configurator.